# Time complexity of logn/loglogn

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Is the time complexity of: `logn/loglogn` is `O(log(n-logn))`?

Also what about `loglogn=O(log(n/logn))`?

I tried to prove both by definition, but I can't find n0,c that work.
I also tried by calculating limit of both functions, but didn't get to inf/0.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework question, but after 3 month it is probably already overdue and so I give a reference answer.

In such cases one can just look for substitution that is easier to compare while preserving the statement.

- `n-log n > n/2` for n big enough. So in big-o we get `O(log(n/2)) = O(log n)` is a subset of `O(log(n-log n))`. Now it is easy to see that `log n / log log n` is in `O(log n)` and thus also in `O(log(n-log n))`.
- the same trick works for the second part of the question with `log n < n/log n`